# Shared preferences gets wiped out, when do you use it then?

Tags: android

I always try to  avoid using shared preferences for storage in my app for the followinng reasons:

- It gets wiped out on device reboot
- It gets wiped out when cache data is cleared
- It gets wiped out on force exit (through task manager)

Which makes me to always resort to internal storage (I/O). However, I see that many people in SO use shared preferences or recommend shared preferences for each  other. Am I missing the point here? In particular, when do you use Shared PReferences?

Thanks you

Comment: `SharedPreferences` are stored in their own file, and don't have the issues you mentioned. Use them when you want to save small things. Otherwise use a db.

Comment: `SharedPreferences` have none of the characteristics that you attribute to them. I have no idea what you think "shared services" are.

Comment: Guys, I am not making this up. I have Galaxy S2. I reboot my device and my shared preferences are gone! I open task manager, exit my current running app, the shared preferences is gone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes a lot of sense for simple things like settings/preferences, and checking whether or not to show an introduction.  I use it in conjunction with syncing to a server.  It is also good to allow the user to clear data associated with your app without going into the file system.

Also, SharedPreferences shouldn't be getting wiped when a device reboots or force closes.

Comment: I have galaxy s2, I reboot my phone and shared pref is wiped out

Comment: For all the apps on your phone, not just the one you're developing?

Comment: Good question. I have seen it in my apps when developing by checking if the sharedPRef that I u updated presists after reboot. How can I check for other apps on the phone? I mean I need access to the code to be able to check shared pref contents, right

Comment: If you go to Settings->Apps and choose an app, it'll show the amount of storage its prefs are taking up.  If you reboot and this decreases even though the app was closed when you rebooted, then it would be getting wiped.

Comment: The storage is not only for prefs. It can also be for  local files created by user. right? But I will check anyways

Answer (score 1):

`SharedPreference` works like a DB but in a small scale:[SharedPreference](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

Comment: Android documentation: This data will persist across user sessions (even if your application is killed).